# Selenium: Stale Element Reference Exception Error

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to loop through all the pages of a website. but I am getting a stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document error. This happens when the script try to click the third page. The script got the error when it runs to page.click(). Any suggestions?

```
    while driver.find_element_by_id('jsGrid_vgAllCases').find_elements_by_tag_name('a')[-1].text=='...':
        links=driver.find_element_by_id('jsGrid_vgAllCases').find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        for link in links:
           if ((link.text !='...') and (link.text !='ADD DOCUMENTS')):
              print('Page Number: '+ link.text)
              print('Page Position: '+str(links.index(link)))
              position=links.index(link)
              page=driver.find_element_by_id('jsGrid_vgAllCases').find_elements_by_tag_name('a')[position]
              page.click()
              time.sleep(5)
        driver.find_element_by_id('jsGrid_vgAllCases').find_elements_by_tag_name('a')[-1].click()
```

Comment: Can you share the URL or HTML source?

Comment: after your click() the DOM is probably updating.  That makes every method call after that throw stale element.  (Because the references you have are no longer valid once the DOM updates.)  Depending on your needs, you can loop through and get the HREFS.  Then use those hrefs in a loop using driver.get()s.  On some sites that may not work (if you can't bookmark links...) so you'd have to flatten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can locate the link element each time again according to the index, not to use elements found initially.
Something like this:

```py
amount = len(driver.find_element_by_id('jsGrid_vgAllCases').find_elements_by_tag_name('a'))
for i in range(1,amount+1):
    link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//*[@id='jsGrid_vgAllCases']//a)["+str(i) +"]")
```

from now you can continue within your for loop with this `link` like this:

```py
amount = len(driver.find_element_by_id('jsGrid_vgAllCases').find_elements_by_tag_name('a'))
for i in range(1,amount+1):
    link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//*[@id='jsGrid_vgAllCases']//a)["+str(i) +"]")
        if ((link.text !='...') and (link.text !='ADD DOCUMENTS')):
            print('Page Number: '+ link.text)
            print('Page Position: '+str(links.index(link)))
            position=links.index(link)
            page=driver.find_element_by_id('jsGrid_vgAllCases').find_elements_by_tag_name('a')[position]
            page.click()
            time.sleep(5)
```

(I'm not sure about the correctness of all the rest your code, just copy-pasted it)

Comment: I am using the following code to relocate the link, why it does not work?            page=driver.find_element_by_id('jsGrid_vgAllCases').find_elements_by_tag_name('a')[position]

Comment: This does work, it gets the web element from the list you collected at the beginning, but since you went to another page or page was refreshed etc - I have no idea what exactly goes there - but the page was changed, so the previously got references no more pointing on those elements since elements were changed. This is the meaning of Stale Element error. This is why you need to get the elements again in order to gain a reference to currently existing element

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into an issue with the Stale Element Exception too.  Interesting with Firefox no problem, Chrome && Edge both fail randomly.  In general i have two generic find method with retry logic, these find methods would look like:

```
     //  Yes C#  but should be relevant for any WebDriver...
     public static IWebElement( this IWebDriver driver, By locator)
     public static IWebElement( this IWebElement element, By locator)
```

The WebDriver variant seems to work fine for my othe fetches as the search is always "fresh"...  But the WebElement search is the one causing grief.  Unfortunately the app forces me to need the WebElement version.  Why he page/html will be something like:

```
    <node id='Best closest ID Possible'>
        <span>
            <div>text i want</div>
            <div>meh ignore this </div>
            <div>More text i want</div>
         </span>
         <span>
         <!-- same pattern ... -->
```

So the code get the closest element possible by id and child spans i.e.  "//*[@id='...']/span" will give all the  nodes of interest.  This is now where i run into issues,  enumerating all  element, will do two XPath select i.e. "./div[1]" and "./div[3]" for pulling out the text desired.  It is only in fetching the text nodes under the  elements where randomly a StaleElement will be thrown.  Sometimes the very first XPath fails,  sometimes i'll go through a few pages, as the pages being might have 10,000's or more pages, while the structure is the same i'll spot check random pages as they all the same format.  At most i've gotten through 20 consecutive pages with Chrome (ver 92.0.4515.107) or Edge (ver 94.0.986),  both seem to be the latest as of now.

One solution that should work, get all the the span elements first, i.e.  '//*[@id='x']/span' get my list then query from the driver like:

````
    var nodeList = driver.FindElements(By.XPath('//*[@id='x']/span' ));

    for( int idx = 0 ; idx < nodeList.Count; idx++) 
    {
    string str1 =  driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='x']/span[idx+1]/div[1]")).GetAttribute("innerText");
    string str2 =  driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='x']/span[idx+1]/div[3]")).GetAttribute("innerText");
    }
```

Think it would work but, YUK!  This is kind of simplified and being able to do an XPath from the respective "ID" located node would be preferable..
````